# The meaning of "You cannot go out and hang out with your friends."

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

My mom said,

> You cannot go out and hang out with your friends.

I know there is only one meaning to this, which is:

> I can't do: go out and hang out with my friends.

**Question:**
If my mom don't want me to do neither of them, she uses

> You cannot go out or hang out with your friends.

Is that right?

Comment: It's not a grey area to your mom. You need to ask her, because both meanings can apply.

Comment: There might be a third meaning if you treat it as two separate sentences. You cannot go out. And hang out with your friends. Of course it's a bit tricky because you have to force your friends to come over to you in order to hang out with them.

Comment: It may be a matter of opinion (as well as too localised) what a particular person intended by these words on a particular occasion, and if that were all that there is to this question, it would indeed be out of the scope of this site. There is, however, a genuine general question here that calls for unpacking the meaning of *and* in such a context, and explaining how it is different from its meaning in logic textbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that the second is more likely, because if you can't go out *for any reason*, then "You can not go out" would be sufficient.

Alternately, "You can not go out *or* hang out with your friends" would emphasize that neither of those things are acceptable. Your other example should really be using "or" as well: "[Y]ou can not drink *or* smoke." Otherwise, it suggests that you can't do *both of them together*, but individually they are okay. Note "Don't drink and drive," for instance. It's okay to drink, and it's okay to drive- but not both at once!

Comment: And in your P.S. when you said you can not do both (drink and smoke), I presume you meant you understood your mom to be telling you you must not do _either_ (neither independently nor concurrently).